# Query module: lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: database, query

I have a query being compiled in a template but by the time it's run, it appears that the query module has lost it's connection to the DB:

```
Error Number: 2013

Lost connection to MySQL server during query

..query here...

Filename: modules/query/mod.query.php

Line Number: 181
```

Is there any way to extend the database connection period so this can be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to increase the [**connect_timeout**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) setting in my.cnf or adjust your query so it processes faster. If you aren't on a VPS, you'll have to contact your host to figure out how you make the my.cnf change in their setup.

Comment: I was looking at that and the default is 10 seconds, however this error displays in less than 1 second of refreshing the page. It's a fairly nasty statement with some nested selects, but there are only 4 rows to query so it wouldn't expect to baulk on a vps with 2gb ram running on it. Or at least not to time out until something more meaningful, like 10 seconds.

Comment: Just ran the query locally in sequel pro and it takes less than 17ms to run. Stumped.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the web host. They might be able to see on their end why the connection is failing.